# Multi Document or Embedded Document in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, social-networking

I'm designing a social network system like twitter, and users will receive notifications, I'm going to persist notifications to mongodb. We will keep 100 notification for each user at most and the only field would be update is `read`(wether user has read the notification). So I am wondering wether using multi document as blow

```
{"userId":1, "content":"some msg", "read":true..}
{"userId":1, "content":"another msg", "read":true..}
```

or using embedded documents like this:

```
{"userId":1, "noficications":[{"content":"some msg", "read": true},{"content":"another msg", "read":true}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt in while ago, when created my app. But in my case, the focus on the app is the values recorded in subdocuments. Then my code became unclear, in some cases. I had some problems to write queries.

If your focus is "User", I don't see any problem in your second approach, but if the focus is "Notifications", I would recommend creating a document to save your notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your usage, If you're always going to load up most/all of the notifications for a given user then I'd keep it in one document with an array on notifications. This will allow the whole document to be mapped in to memory and will keep things snappy. Also you won't have to create any extra indexes.

```
{"_id":1 /* User Id */, "noficications":[{"content":"some msg", "read": true},{"content":"another msg", "read":true}]}
```

However if you are going to be pulling back adhoc individual notification, I'd split it down in to seperate documents, as you won't want to be keeping the whole document hot in memory. for this apporach you might end up creating another index on "userId" so you can pull back all notifications at once.

```
{"_id": 1 /* Notification Id */, "userId":1, "content":"some msg", "read":true..}
{"_id": 2 /* Notification Id */, "userId":1, "content":"another msg", "read":true..}
```

There's pros/cons to both and it all depends on your usage of data.

Comment: I wanted to use embedded array, but a little worried the performance. As these articles mentioned: [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/8R0UwurbbyE), [2](http://www.askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays/), the performance might be a problem. What if the array size is limit to 100? Will it cause performance problem?

Comment: If your limiting the amount of items returns to the client per request single documents is going to be more efficient as the array will take up more working space  and you'll also have to get mongo to slice it

Comment: But if using single documents, it's hard to limit users' document count to a certain number. In that case, I should set up a scheduling program and iterate all documents which will be inefficient, right?

Comment: As long as you've got the appropriate index then it will never touch disk on doing a count